# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to set Guake to Righ Click "Open in Terminal" instead of default?

Tags: gnome-terminal, guake

Wondered if someone could help?

FInally went full ubuntu for work and fair play, except for the odd annoyances (mainly due to the laptop im running but i managed to get around them) im loving it :)

So I really liked the look of Guake (fan of Quake too :) ) and decided to install it.  Instantly its just way better than the classic look for termianl (though I use F12 alot if chrome for debugging so I should change that in Guake) but what I want to do is change the default of "Open In Terminal) when I right click in a filder to be able to open in Guake instead.

I followed this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

I managed to set it to "Default":

```
Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/guake                    40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/guake                    40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
```

Though the system still doesnt seem to listen to that option.

Does anyone know how I can manage to do this easily?

Cheers

Comment: I don't know how to do it. However, here are some alternatives http://askubuntu.com/questions/152193/how-to-open-directory-in-guake-from-nautilus and http://askubuntu.com/questions/756886/how-to-write-a-script-to-open-current-path-from-nautilus-in-guake